# how to use OpenAI Whisper in C#

Tags: ironpython, speech-to-text, openai-whisper

I'm new in C#
i want to make voice assistant in C# and use Whisper for Speech-To-Text.
I want use IronPython for use python in c# because I can't use Whisper in C#.

this is my python code:

```
import replicate
import os

os.environ['REPLICATE_API_TOKEN'] = '73xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

model = replicate.models.get("openai/whisper")
version = model.versions.get("30414ee7c4fffc37e260fcab7842b5be470b9b840f2b608f5baa9bbef9a259ed")

inputs = {

    'audio': open(r"C:\Users\JAHAN TEEGH\Documents\Sound recordings\Recording.mp3", "rb"),

    'model': "large",

    'temperature': 0,

    'suppress_tokens': "-1",

    'condition_on_previous_text': True,

    'temperature_increment_on_fallback': 0.2,

    'compression_ratio_threshold': 2.4,

    'logprob_threshold': -1,

    'no_speech_threshold': 0.6,
}

result = version.predict(**inputs)
print(result['segments'][0]['text'])
```

this is my C# code:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System;

ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"D:\code\Dastak\stt\py.py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);
dynamic result = scope.GetVariable("v");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

i have this error:

```
Unhandled exception. IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named 'replicate'
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.ThrowException(LightException lightEx)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow(Object value)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\code\Dastak\stt\myApp\Program.cs:line 34
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I can't help with IronPython, if your goal is to just run whisper from C#, you can probably try to use this lib https://github.com/sandrohanea/whisper.net/tree/0d1f691b3679c4eb2d97dcebafda1dc1d8439215.

If you are still interested in running python from C#, I can advice PythonNet.

I was able to run it after I configured regular python libs with steps from tutorial https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/how-to-run-openais-whisper-speech-recognition-model/. The only difference, I used following command to translate the text

```
whisper gettysburg10.wav --model tiny --device cpu --fp16 False
```

Then I wrote following code in C#:

```
        var pythonDllLocation = "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.dll";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", pythonDllLocation);

        PythonEngine.Initialize();

        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            var whisper = Py.Import("whisper");
            var model = whisper.InvokeMethod("load_model", new PyString("tiny"));
            var result = model.InvokeMethod("transcribe", new PyString(tbInputFile.Text));

            WriteConsole(result["text"].As<string>());
        }
```

Path to Pythopn38.dll might be different. You can get it with  `where python38.dll`

PythonNet has dynamics api, but fluent is a bit more comfortable for me, although they should work the same way.

Comment: How can I add named parameters to transcribe method? How to set transcribe language in C#?